# Integral of integral function

Tags: octave

I am struggling trying to evaluate numerically on Octave a double integral of a user defined function on one variable.

Here is the function:

```matlab
function result = Sigma1(ec)
    ec2 = -0.001;
    fcd = 20e6;
    if(ec >= 0)
        result = 0;
        return;
    endif
    if(ec > ec2)
        result = -fcd.*(1-(1-ec./ec2).^2);
        return;
    endif
    result = -fcd;
endfunction
```

The function works as expected:

```
>> integral(@Sigma1, 0, -0.003)
ans = 6.0000e+04
```

but if I try to integrate two times I get:

```
>> integral(integral(@Sigma1, 0, -0.003), 0, -0.003)
error: feval: first argument must be a string, inline function, or a function handle
error: called from
    integral at line 123 column 36
```

I tried also a double integral:

```
>> integral2(@Sigma1, 0, e, 0, e)
error: Sigma1: function called with too many inputs
```

Edit1:

I also tried integral2 with:

```matlab
function result = Sigma2(ec, foo)
    ec2 = -0.001;
    fcd = 20e6;
    if(ec >= 0)
        result = 0;
        return;
    endif
    if(ec > ec2)
        result = -fcd.*(1-(1-ec./ec2).^2);
        return;
    endif
    result = -fcd;
endfunction
```

but the result is looks wrong:

```
>> integral2(@Sigma2, 0, -0.003, 0, -0.003)
ans = -180
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide details on what specific issue you have and provide code that replicates the issue. Also, have you tried [`integral2`](https://docs.octave.org/latest/Functions-of-Multiple-Variables.html#XREFintegral2)?

Comment: Note that there is no integral1 function. Just integral.  Second, the integral2 function tells you the problem - your function only takes one input but integral2 expects your function to have two inputs (making it two dimensional). The error is telling you one integral function is trying to call it like Sigma1(x,y)

Comment: @NickJ Sorry, I wrote integral1 instead of integral. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I came up with this solution:

```matlab
function y = Sigma1Int(x)
  y = integral(@Sigma1, 0, x, 'ArrayValued', true);
endfunction

function y = Sigma1IntInt(x)
  y = integral(@Sigma1Int, 0, x, 'ArrayValued', true);
endfunction

function y = Sigma1IntInt(x)
  y = integral(@Sigma1Int, 0, x, 'ArrayValued', true);
endfunction
```

and the results are as expected:

```
>> Sigma1IntInt(-0.003)
ans = -56.667
>> Sigma1IntIntInt(-0.003)
ans = 0.047333
>>
```